# Finding 1/(2+1/(3+1/(4+...)))

Tags: continued-fractions

I was wondering how to find the value of the following series:

$$\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{5+\cfrac{1}{6+\ddots}}}}}$$

How can I solve this?

Comment: It equals $$\frac{I_0(2)}{I_1(2)}-1 = 0.43312742672231\ldots $$ where $I_k$ are modified Bessel functions of the first kind.

Comment: Incidental question ... what search in the math.se search box would have found that duplicate question?